# Error running AngularJS ES6

Tags: html, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to run a simple AngularJS example using the latest ES6 syntax in html. Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Basic Angular JS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="es6-shim@0.32.2" data-semver="0.32.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.32.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SampleCtrl as sc">
    <h3>Hello {{sc.firstName + " " + sc.lastName}}!</h3>
</div>

<script>
(function(){
    'use strict';
    class SampleCtrl {
        constructor () {
            this.firstName = "John";
            this.lastName = "Doe";
            console.log("ctrl works");
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
})();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't really know what I'm missing here but I keep getting the following errors in console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=app ...
>   Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app ...

My html output in browser:

```
Hello {{sc.firstName + " " + sc.lastName}}!
```

**Update:** Fixed module declaration as:

```
angular
        .module('app', [])
        .controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
```

But now I'm getting the following error in console:

> TypeError: Class constructor SampleCtrl cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the app incorrectly I believe:

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
```

Try that instead

Comment: Fixed that... Now I'm getting error in console: TypeError: Class constructor SampleCtrl cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: @BangularTK Try 1.5.x. I don't remember when exactly this was fixed but I believe it was.

Comment: @estus YESSS! I tried 1.6.x and it works like a charm now!! I cannot thank you enough! :)

Comment: @BangularTK You're welcome. There were some updates from Angular team on ES6 a year ago or so, but I thought they were already available in 1.4.8.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
```

If you are using to retrieve an existing module, You can use

```
 angular.module('app').controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
```

if you are creating a new module or overwrite any existing module, you use like this,

```
 angular.module('app',[]).controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem finally fixed by using Angular JS version 1.6.x

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer BangularTK was already confirmed, but I'd like to offer an alternative for cases where people are not ready to update to a newer version of AngularJS for any reason.

I'm using 1.4.7 and I faced the exact same issue once I refactored a controller from a function into a ES6 class.

> TypeError: Class constructor Classname cannot be invoked without 'new'

In order to work it around without updating AngularJS, I wrapped the construction of my class into a function.

In this example, it would like like:

```
<script>
(function(){
    'use strict';
    class SampleCtrl {
        constructor () {
            this.firstName = "John";
            this.lastName = "Doe";
            console.log("ctrl works");
        }
    }

    function SampleCtrlWrapper() {
        return new SampleCtrl();
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('SampleCtrl', SampleCtrlWrapper);
})();

</script>
```

Again, not the best solution, but a temporary workaround to buy time before you update your AngularJS dependency.